# CSS display type table-row elements height in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, tablerow

I use several content blocks on my single page application http://geolytix.com

Here is an example block:

```
<div class="section" id="section_geodata">
  <p class="title">Geodata</p>
  <div class="table-row__spacer"></div>
  <p class="intro">Where people live...</p>
  <div class="table-row__spacer"></div>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="select">
      <div class="select__inner">
        <div class="cursor retail_points selected">Retail Points</div>
        <div class="cursor retail_places">Retail Places</div>
        <div class="cursor seamless_locales">Seamless Locales</div>
        <div class="cursor town_suburbs">Town and Suburb</div>
        <div class="cursor postal_geom">Postal Geometries</div>
        <div class="cursor public_transport">Public Transport</div>
        <div class="cursor road_network">Road Network</div>
        <div class="cursor uk_admin">UK Admin</div>
        <div class="cursor education">Education</div>
        <div class="cursor poi">Points of Interest</div>
        <div class="cursor pricing">Pricing</div>
        <div class="cursor faq">FAQ</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content map">
      <div id="map_geodata"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

These blocks should be no higher than the browser window height. I set for example the section_geodata height like this.

```
#section_geodata {
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 95px);
}
```

I display the block as a table since I want to display the inner elements as table-rows in order to make use of auto height for these elements.

The css of the other elements is as follows:

```
#section_geodata {
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 95px);
}
#section_geodata > .title {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
#section_geodata > .table-row__spacer:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: table-row;
    height: 30px;
}
#section_geodata > .intro {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
#section_geodata > .table-row__spacer:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: table-row;
    height: 40px;
}
#section_geodata > .container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    height: auto;
}
#section_geodata > .container > .select {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#section_geodata > .container > .select > .select__inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0;
}
#section_geodata > .container > .content {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#section_geodata > .container > .map {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
#section_geodata > .container > .map > #map_geodata {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This works great with Chrome, IE & Edge but doesn't work with Firefox. The table-row elements do not resize as expected.

It would be great if someone has an idea to achieve the same layout which works with other browser.

Comment: Use `table-cell` instead of `table-row`, I know it doesn't seem right but the `display: table-* ` properties aren't 100% .

Comment: Thanks for the comment... I already just found another solution which works.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution after the suggestion to not use height:auto for the .select container or height:0 for the table-row items.

I changed height:auto for height:100% for the .select container and height: 1px instead of height: 0 for the table-rows. The layout and sizing is now the same across the different browser.